# Add search filter to Angular-6-datatable

Tags: angular

I am trying to add a search filter on top of my Angular data table(I'm not too fussed with it's positioning right now). I am using Angular-6-datatable (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-6-datatable) and bootstrap. I have created a stackblitz project here.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-utd8cc

I just want to be able to search the 'Name' column. Please assist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add a separate array for your filtered data and bind your table to it:

> ts file

```
search(term: string) {
    if(!term) {
      this.filterData = this.data;
    } else {
      this.filterData = this.data.filter(x => 
         x.name.trim().toLowerCase().includes(term.trim().toLowerCase())
      );
    }
  }
```

> html

```
<input type="text" (keyup)='search($event.target.value)'>
```

Comment: It does not remove any rows

Comment: @NimaHakimi Hi tried this code is working, But after doing any other button click for any changes in array after that, this is not triggering.. Can u please help me out on this.

Answer (score 3):

i Think Your Requirement is Custom Filters in Data table.

Component.html

```
        <form (ngSubmit)="filterById($event)">
          <label> 
            First Name
            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" />


          </label>
          <label>
            Last Name
            <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name"/>



          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
        <br />

        <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover"></table>
```

Component.ts

```
                export class DatatableComponent implements OnInit {
              @ViewChild(DataTableDirective)
              datatableElement: DataTableDirective;
              private new_url = 'service_url';
              Search$: Observable<Person>;

              constructor(private personservice: PersonService, private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
              send_data_service: any = {};
              dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};




              ngOnInit(): void {

               this.dtOptions = {
                  ajax: this.new_url,
                  columns: [{
                    title: 'id',
                    data: 'id'
                  }, {
                    title: 'first_name',
                    data: 'first_name'
                  }, {
                    title: 'last_name',
                    data: 'last_name',
                  },

                  ]

                };

              }


              filterById(event: any) {



                const first_name = event.target.first_name.value;
                const last_name = event.target.last_name.value;

                this.send_data_service = { 'first_name': first_name, 'last_name': last_name };
                  this.datatableElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
                  this.personservice.searchData(this.send_data_service)
                    .subscribe(data =>
                      this.send_data_service = data);

                  dtInstance.search(first_name).draw();




              }

            }
```

You can implement custom filters in datatable.

Comment: Thank you, will try this in the future

Answer (score 1):

You could filter using a [Subject](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html) and [the Array filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter).

In the component code :

```
data$ = new Subject<any>();

filter(search) {
    this.data$.next(this.data.filter(_ => _.name.includes(search)));
}
```

And in the template just replace the `data` with `data$ | async`.

[Here is a running edit of your code.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-52739260)

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 array lists i.e: `rows =[]; permanentRows = []; temp = [];`

While getting the data from API, initialize both the arrays i.e:

```
get_data_from_api(data=>{
    this.rows = data,
    this.permanentRows = data
 }
 )
```

```
updateFilter(event) {
    const val = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    if(val) {
        this.temp = this.rows;
        // filter our data
        const temp = this.temp.filter(function (d) {
          return ( d.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || d.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val);
        });
        // update the rows
        this.rows = temp;            
    }
    else
    {
        this.rows = this.permanentRows;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just assume this is the data fetch from server:**
**data.service.ts**

```
let posts = [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut",
    "body": "quia et"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "ea molestias quasi"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "eum et est occaecati",
    "body": "ullam et saepe"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 5,
    "title": "nesciunt quas odio",
    "body": "repudiandae veniam"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 6,
    "title": "dolorem eum magni eos aperiam quia",
    "body": "ut aspernatur"
  }
]

getPost() {
   return this.posts;
}
```

**In HTML displaying this data in tabular format using *ngFor directive:**
Syntax:

```
<input type="text" value="" (input)="searchData($event.target.value)">

   <tr *ngFor="let post of filteredPost">
       <td>Data display here..</td>
   </tr>
```

**In TS:**

```
let post:any[] = [];

let filteredPost: any[] = [];

constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

ngOnInit() {
   this.post = this.dataService.getPost();
   this.filteredPost = this.post;
}

searchData(searchText: string) {
    if(!searchText) {
      this.filteredPost = this.post;
    } else {
        this.filteredPost = this.post?.filter(post => 
        post.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()))
    }
}
```